# MERN Delete request issues

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, axios, mern

I'm wokring on a simple suggestion app it has authenctication and context api for State management, I can create, read, update and delete a suggestion but I've been trying to make a delete request but its not working.
I console.log the error message due to the conditional statement and its saying
**Request failed with status code 403**
I've tried everything but its not working

this is my code on expresss

```
router.delete("/bmi/delete/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  try {
    const suggest = await bmiCalc.findById(id);
    if (suggest.userId === req.body.userId) {
      await suggest.deleteOne();
      res.status(200).json("Suggestion deleted");
    } else {
      res.status(403).json("Not your Suggestion to delete");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json("Error from server");
  }
});
```

This is the react axios request

```
const Home = () => {
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const handleSuggestion = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const fullDetail = {
      userId: user.users._id,
      bmiNumber: bmiNumber.current.value,
      country: country.current.value,
      messages: messages.current.value,
    };
    const res = await axios.post(
      "http://localhost:5000/app/bmi/bmiform/create",
      fullDetail,
    );
    setData([...data, res.data]);
    console.log(res.data);
  };

  const reload = () => {
    window.location.reload();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const getSuggestion = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get(
        `http://localhost:5000/app/bmi/all/${user.users._id}`,
      );
      await setData(res.data);
    };
    getSuggestion();
  }, [user.users._id]);

  const handleDelete = async (id) => {
    try {
      await axios.delete(`http://localhost:5000/app/bmi/delete/${id}`, {
        data: { userId: user.users._id },
      });

      setData(data.filter((post) => post._id !== id));
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
  };
```

I'm using chakra UI, here is the button for the onclick event

```
<Flex
        w={"100%"}
        h={"60vh"}
        padding={"8px"}
        gap={"8px"}
        flexWrap={"wrap"}
        justifyContent={"flex-start"}>
        {data.map((data) => {
          return (
            <Box
              key={data._id}
              width={["47%", "55%", "25%", "24%"]}
              height={["55%", "50%", "50%", "50%"]}
              bg={"#ffffff"}
              display={"flex"}
              flexDirection={"column"}
              borderRadius={7}
              gap={4}
              padding={5}>
              <Box w={"100%"} h={"5vh"} transition={"0.3s all"}>
                <p className='boxTitle'> BMI: {data.bmiNumber}</p>
                <p className='boxCountry'> {data.country}</p>
              </Box>
              <Box width={"100%"} height={"100%"} paddingTop={2}>
                <p className='boxMessage'> {data.messages}</p>
              </Box>
              <Flex width={"100%"} gap={1}>
                <Button
                  bg={"#541db5"}
                  type='submit'
                  width='100%'
                  outline='none'
                  border='none'
                  borderRadius={6}
                  color='#ffffff'
                  fontSize={20}
                  fontWeight={600}
                  marginBottom={4}
                  padding={4}>
                  edit
                </Button>
                {data.userId === user?.users._id && (
                  <Button
                    onClick={() => handleDelete(data._id)}
                    type='submit'
                    width='100%'
                    outline='none'
                    border='none'
                    borderRadius={6}
                    color='#ffffff'
                    fontSize={20}
                    fontWeight={600}
                    bg='#ef233c'
                    marginBottom={4}
                    padding={4}>
                    <DeleteIcon />
                  </Button>
                )}
              </Flex>
            </Box>
          );
        })}
      </Flex>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had this issue and fixed it a couple of minutes ago.

So basically MongoDB doesn't see those objectIds as equal

The best option to compare them is using `suggest.userId.equals(req.body.userId)`
this will result in true

Answer (score 1):

try console logging both of these too see why they are not equal.

suggest.userId

req.body.userId

Then investigate why they are not equal.

Comment: console.log message says **false**  i'm trying to check why they are not equal

Comment: @sms answer below, looks to be why

Answer (score 0):

In your router you need to access userId as

```
 req.body.data.userId
```

instead of

```
req.body.userId
```